# switching the order of two arguments in a function

Tags: python

Is there a standard way to switch the order by which an argument is passed into a function?

for e.g.

```
def verse_maker(sent1, sent2):
    do stuff

verse_maker(arg1, arg2)
```

switch the position of the arguments such that:

```
verse_maker(arg2, arg1)
```

edit: I mean to say, without having to manually call the function again. I would like the function to run twice with the arguments in those two different configurations.

Comment: Yes. Swap the order of the arguments in the function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think theres any easier way than the way you've written it here?.. I wouldn't expect your program to work correctly though.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, there is no standard way to call a function twice with the order swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def verse_maker(sent1, sent2):
  do stuff

verse_maker(sent2=arg2, sent1=arg1)
```

But I don't see why you don't simply swap the args around? Its much shorter

Edit: Seen your edit, I'm not exactly sure what you are saying, you want the code to run twice without calling it twice? I guess you can put a loop inside the code so it runs 2 times and swap the arguments around at the end of the first loop?

Edit 2: So here is what I believe you are looking for

```
def verse_maker(sent1, sent2):
  for i in range(2):
    do stuff
    sent2, sent1 = sent1, sent2
```

This will swap the variables at the end of the loop, and re run the code with swapped variables

Comment: one small question, why not placing the loop in the calling function instead of the called function. That way the called function remains side effect free.

Comment: I placed it inside the function because it seems like OP wants to call the function at other points and each time have it do the function on both orders of the arguments. Of course you are right, that if you only wanted to do this once, you would place the for loop around the function call itself. But OP said they don't want to call the function multiple times, so I went with the loop inside the function

Comment: That was precisely my point. If we take the loop out of the called function and place it in the calling function then it will not matter whether we call the function once or twice. We can do whatever we want but the function, as an `atomic unit`, will always work as expected. What do you think?

Comment: I agree with keeping the function intact. My logic is that if OP doesn't want to write the call function twice, he will not want to write a for loop every time he needs to call it. But yes, in good practice, you should keep the called function intact, I just have a feeling that's not what OP is looking for. I will happily edit it once we hear from OP and see what he says

Comment: I added the alternative approach :)

Comment: Yup, I definitely agree that your method is the "cleaner" way to implement it :p

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, IMHO the solution provided works but it has the side effect of placing the loop inside the function itself. I would like to propose this instead

```
def verse_maker(sent1, sent2):
    do stuff

for i in range(0,2):
    verse_maker(arg1, arg2)
    arg1, arg2 = arg2, arg1
```

I just took the loop out of the function and placed it where we are calling it. That way it will not matter how many times we call this function. It will always produce the desired result.